# How can I highlight the source cells in a formula (e.g. =SHEETA!$E$568 )

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

I have a sheet that makes extensive use of cells from another sheet with formulas, some of which have errors.  The formulas look like:

```
=SHEETA!$E$568
```

Is there a way, or a script, that can parse the formula and either let me jump to, view, or in another tab, highlight cell `SHEETA!$E$568`?

Desktop Microsoft Excel once had a feature that drew lines from the source cells to the formula: this would be a similar use case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script.
To access it, either put it in a custom menu or create a shortcut.

```
function jumpto() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  // create variables
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell()
  var formula = activeCell.getFormula()
  var cellref = formula.substring(1)
  var sheet = cellref.slice(0,cellref.indexOf('!'));


  var resp = ui.alert('Jump to '+cellref,'Are you sure you want to continue?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    // Process the user's response.
    if (resp == ui.Button.YES) {
      // User clicked "Yes".
      // create sheet variable
      var targetsheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet)
      var range = ss.getRange(formula.substring(1))
      targetsheet.setActiveSelection(range);
  } else {
      // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
      ui.alert('Jump cancelled.');
  }

}
```

---

**Logic**

- `Ui` is used to confirm that the user wants to jump
- the formula in the active cell is obtained
- `=` is stripped off using `.substring(1)`
- the sheet is obtained using `cellref.indexOf('!')`